# How to force `git range-diff` to display line numbers?

Tags: git, git-range-diff

My git version is 2.28.0

When I did `git range-diff HASH...HASH` I get:

[image]

But how to force `git range-diff` to display lines, like usual diff/show does:

`git show 4b8f08e8`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with `git range-diff` and the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-range-diff) doesn't say anything about this. You will have to `git show HASH` the commits to see the lines.